# How to create an ASP.NET MVC 3.2.7 page with 3 view models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 3.2.7 web site. I have the following Entity Framework 6.4.4 database model:

```
[Table("Report")]
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public class ReportId { get; set; }

    // Other irrelevant properties

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<DataSection> DataSections
    {
        get
        {
             return ReportDataSections
                    .OrderBy(rds => rds.OrderSeq)
                    .Select(rds => rds.DataSection);
        }
    }

    public virtual IColledction<ReportDataSection> ReportDataSections { get; } = new List<ReportDataSection>();
}

[Table("DataSection")]
public class DataSection
{
    [Key]
    public int DataSectionId { get; set; }

    // Other irrelevant properties

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Report> Reports
    {
        get
        {
             return ReportDataSections
                    .OrderBy(rds => rds.Report.ReportName)
                    .Select(rds => rds.Report);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ReportDataSection> ReportDataSections { get; } => new List<ReportDataSection();
}

[Table("ReportDataSection")]
public class ReportDataSection
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Oder = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Oder = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int DataSectionId { get; set; }

    public int OrderSeq { get; set; }

    public virtual DataSection DataSection { get; set; }

    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

I want the home page of the site to look something like this:

[image: Home Page Mockup]

I have a number of view models:

- `DataSourcesViewModel`: this has an `ICollection<DataSourceViewModel>` right now.
- `ReportsViewModel`: this has an `ICollection<ReportsViewModel>` right now.
- `DataSectionsViewModel`: this has an `ICollection<DataSectionViewModel>` right now.
- `HomePageViewModel: this has three properties, a` DataSourcesViewModel`, and a` ReportsViewModel`, a` DataSectionsViewModle`.

Here's the `HomeController` class:

```
public class HomePageController : Controller
{
    private readonly HomePageViewModel _viewModel = new HomePageViewModel();

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: DataSources
    public ActionResult DataSources()
    {
        return View("DataSources", _viewModel.DataSources);
    }

    // GET: Reports
    public ActionResult Reports()
    {
        return View("Reports", _viewModel.DataSources);
    }

    // GET: DataSections
    public ActionResult DataSections()
    {
        return View("DataSections", _viewModel.DataSections);
    }
}
```

This class doesn't compile. I'm getting an error because the `ViewModel` classes aren't `IEnumerables`. Yet this code looks like other examples I've seen, especially the one with the Log-in and Registration forms.

In any event, I've created partial views, one for each tab in the tab control. The `Index` page looks like this:

```
@model HomePageViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "...";
    ViewBag.DataSources = "...";
    ViewBag.DatSections = "...";
    ViewBag.Reports = "...";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>@ViewBag.DataSources</h4>
    @Html.RenderPartial("DataSources", Model.DataSources)
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>@ViewBag.Reports</h4>
    @Html.RenderPartial("Reports", Model.Reports)
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>@ViewBag.DataSections</h4>
    @Html.RenderPartial("DataSections", Model.DataSections)
</div>
```

None of this is building. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How do I get this to work.

Comment: May I ask why you are using an obsolete and unsupported version of ASP.NET MVC - and why can't you update the assembly-references to ASP.NET 4.8 MVC?

Comment: Part of the problem is you're re-using (Linq-to-Sql?) Table Entities as "raw" ViewModels. That's an anti-pattern that _looks like_ it saves time but inevitably always causes problems down-the-line.

Comment: @Dai: I work for a financial institution that has things pretty locked down. That was the most recent version I had found for .NET Framework (the Framework is a long story; We're going to be upgrading to .NET Core soon but I'm using internal DLLs that are still on the old Framework). No, I'm not using those classes as View Models. I just didn't include the View Models in the queston.